# Is there a default timeout in Node.js for http.request?

Tags: node.js

In Node.js there is a **default timeout for a server** (for an incoming HTTP request) at 120000ms (2 minutes) (see [HTTP's `server.timeout` documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout)).

But if **I want to do an HTTP request in Node.js (using `http.request`)**,  looking at the documentation, I only find a function [request.setTimeout()](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_settimeout_timeout_callback) to set the timeout manually.

Anyone know if there is a default timeout for HTTP requests in Node.js? Or does Node.js try to send the HTTP request with no end?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You want to set the [`server.timeout`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback) property (it defaults to 120,000, as you've found).

---

Update: Node.js 13 has removed the default timeout:

- https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#servertimeout
- https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/27558

Comment: no, i asked if there is a default timeout-property for http.request (not server)

Comment: @user3351722 adjusting the `server.timeout` will impact `http-request`.

Comment: How to make this to infinite timeout?

Comment: @Govan, from the looks of https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout , "A value of 0 will disable the timeout behavior on incoming connections."

Comment: Node.js 13 has removed the default timeout. (https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/27558)

Comment: @SomeKittens this answer should be edited as the new version (v. 13) sets the default timeout to 0 (no timeout)

Answer (score 7):

I was also interested in this. By reading the code, Node.js uses Socket under the hood of http request (naturally). (The source link below is referring v8.8.0 at the point when I'm writing this)

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_http_outgoing.js

And Socket does not have the timeout by default by this document

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/net.html#net_socket_settimeout_timeout_callback

And the source tells the same.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/net.js

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no default timeout.

Node.js uses Socket under the hood of http request and socket does not have the timeout by default.

Use the {timeout: XX} parameter of http.request to configure a proper request timeout.

Comment: Do you know, and can elaborate about what kind of timeout this is?
Is it timeout to create a connection? Timeout for an idle connection not being used?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid default server timeouts and customize your needs, then this may can help you!

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.set('serverTimeout', 300000); // here you can set time as your need

... //rest for your codes!
```

- Time will be counted as millisecond.