# What is the default timeout for http request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https

For the NodeJS `https` library, what is the default timeout for the `http.Agent` and `http.Request`? I was checking the [documentation for the agent](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_new_agent_options) and [the documentation for the request](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_url_options_callback). Every field has a default listed except for timeout. What is it? Is it infinite for both? Lastly, can I set the timeout in the Agent and not the request? I'm assuming you can set it in the agent so that it will apply to any request using the agent. Otherwise, you can set it on the request so only that request will have the specified timeout.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214902/how-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-http-request-in-node

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874954/is-there-a-default-timeout-in-node-js-for-http-request

Comment: @ulou Thanks, but that is the server timeout not the request timeout as far as I can tell